# Net Core Multiple Lifetimes for a single object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out a work around for using multiple lifetimes with DbContexts.  I register My Contexts like so in my start up.

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<CustomContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

I would like to get out an isolated context so it doesn't effect my entities and so I can run async queries on the db:

```
serviceProvider.GetRequiredServiceAsLifetime<AstootContext>(Lifetime.Scoped);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't effect my entities"? Why do you need an isolated context for those queries?

Comment: Because I’m running code to validate a user in jwt middlewear async, but entityframework limitations don’t allow them to run async so I need to create a new context, but for other reasons I cannot use scoped

Comment: What if you add separate DbContext for your "special" purpose: services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<CustomCo‌​ntext>( options => options.UseSqlServer(connection)); services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<CustomContext1>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

Comment: I’ve tried that as well it reuses the same connection for some reason